# What's the word for when you are told to do something but you don't do it?

Tags: single-word-requests

for example- father is mad at me when I ***** what he told me to do.

Comment: Have you looked up antonyms for *comply?*

Comment: Father is mad at me when I don't do what he's told me to.

Comment: I did so now! and the word I was looking for was "disobey". Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Note that although you can ***disobey your father***, or ***disobey an order*** (perhaps issued by your father), I can't help thinking there's something not quite right about saying *I disobeyed **what he told me to do***.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a phrase that will make you sound like a native speaker, **"blow off"**, is very mainstream. As in:

"I've got a lot of work to do - I'm going to *blow off* that meeting."
(I'm not going to the meeting)

"My sister asked me to help her move, but, I *blew* her *off*."
(I didn't help.)

"Fred *blew off* class because he had to *blow off* the test he didn't study for." 
(Fred didn't show up for class because he did not want to take the test.) (US)